# Docker image created from environment, pushed to a registry, pulled from a server... now what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I started to use Docker a few days ago so I'm still a newbie in this domain, so I deeply apologize if my questions seem obvious, because so far, most of them aren't for me.

My goal is to create a custom image from a Rails application, to send it up to the Docker Hub, then pull it from a server and simply make it run.

I used [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) to create my image excepted that I chose to use MariaDB (works fine). So far, my project only contains a CRUD / scaffold that works nicely.

I then pushed it to a private repository on Docker Hub using [this link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/). Again, no problem, hub is telling me the push went okay, same for my console.

Then, I connected to a private server running Debian, pulled the project from the hub, made sure it existed using `docker images`.

My main question is the following: **what should I do next?**

If I refer to the first link, I create the rails project from close to empty Gemfile, then synchronise the local files with the image. However, on my server, all I have is an empty directory. If I'm not stupid, redoing the Docker's tutorial will "reset" my image.

This is where I'm currently lost: what should I do now? I don't believe that running `docker run repo/my-image rails server` is the good solution here

Thank you in advance

Comment: docker run repo/my-image rails server  is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going good till now. Now think what is the use of you pushing the image to private repository - You and others who have access to repo should be able to get the image and should be able to create containers from it.

The point where you lost is exactly what you should do now i.e. execute `docker run`

> redoing the Docker's tutorial will "reset" my image.

Docker is smart enough to download image once and use again. Resetting will remove your locally downloaded images but it won't remove from private repo.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I now have to figure a way to link my repository to a docker-compose file, thank you!